# Simulator rotation locked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I just started the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1) of creating apps in Xcode for `iOS 7.0+`.

However, when I run the app, and rotate the device in the *iOS simulator*, the position of the app stays fixed in the portrait mode, while the screen does change to landscape size. This should clearly not happen since it just works in the tutorial.

Can someone help me fix this?

Edit 1: 
I have ticked all boxed, which did not help. Also I added the code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

if ( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  || interfaceOrientation   == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation ==    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    return YES; // for supported orientations

return NO;
}
```

Which did nothing either, I also already noticed that an array of `supported interface orientation` already exists. Maybe the problem is the *iOS Simulator*

Edit 2:
Sorry for my stupidity, the rotation lock of iOS was on for some reason... Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is happening because you didn't set landscape orientation for the app.

[image]

### ***Xcode default set as Potrait orientation only.***

Comment: I ticked the Portrait box, but also the Landscape left and the Landscape right box (which was told), but it still doesn't rotate when I rotate the screen. When I only select landscape left and right, it simulates the app perfectly fine in landscape left mode. However, if I then try to rotate to Landscape right, the app is still fixed in Landscape left and won't rotate.

BTW, the iPad simulator does rotate

Comment: search for `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your project  and let me know if you have any code for this... If yes, edit your question and post it there...

Comment: Apparently it does not contain such a function, so I presume I have to add it myself like said in the other comments?

Comment: @DanielsWrath : If you have clicked all 4 option for orientation, then it should work properly for all 4 orientations...

Comment: @DanielsWrath I am facing same type of issue. In my app, iPhone simulator works on all orientation except upsidedown. The same app on iPad, works for all four orientations. Any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

open your project, find your_projetname-info.plist file,
add to him new row and write here

```
Supported interface orientations
```

this will create in your plist file an array field with supported orientations as elements.
add new elements (pressing +) and choise from droplist orientation than you need.

also you can do this in code (your AppDelegate) 
by adding

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

if ( interfaceOrientation == <needed_interface_orientation> || interfaceOrientation ==<another_needed_interfaceOrientation>)
        return YES; // for supported orientations

return NO;
}
```

after this you must read apple autolayout guide (link sugested by

> raurora )

Comment: How do I do this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about Auto Layout and more specifically how to set constraints.

There is Ray's [Video Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout) on Auto Layout and the [Beginning Auto Layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) blog post for iOS 7. Maybe you give the rich Apple documentation a chance: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW1)

**EDIT** -
Okay, my answer got downvoted. That means the I should give an example - may be duplicate the problem. When I made my first app, I got the same problem. Screenshot below, are you in the same boat?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, the rotation was locked in the simulator... But thanks for the links to the tutorials, i'll take a look at those!